# Problems with \hat+ and spacing

Tags: math-mode

Having an arbitrary document, inside math mode spacing works great when addition is used.

`x'=x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n`

but when `+` changes to `\hat+` like in

`x'=x_1 \hat+ x_2 \hat+ \cdots \hat+ x_n`

the spacing does not work well.

Comment: `\mathbin{\hat{+}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\mathbin{\hat{+}}`. Or define a macro

```
\newcommand*\hatplus{\mathbin{\hat{+}}}
```

I thought it was necessary to add `\DOTSB` to give the info to `\dots` to see wether use center dots or lower dots, but it seems that it's intelligent enough to see `\mathbin`.